# Audio is also be cancelled which overlap with acoustic echo when using WebRtc_Aecm on Android

Tags: android, webrtc, aec

As an example:

PCM captured by microphone:

1, {2,3} {4,5} {6,7}, 8, 9,

{A,B} means A is the audio data I really want to capture, B is the echo at the same time.
A and B both captured by mic at the same time.

The issue I encounter: the audio 2, 4 and 6 are also cancelled while cancelling 3, 5 and 7.

This is my code:

```
WebRtcAecm_Init( &aecm , 8000 );
While ( aecProcessing )
{
    WebRtcAecm_BufferFarend( speakerBuffer );
    WebRtcAecm_Process( aecm , micBuffer , NULL , aecBuffer , 160 , 200 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if you run a loopback testing, the normal voice can be cancelled partially.
2. don't use constant delay like 200ms, cus' this delay is always changes, you should estimate it every 1 second or shorter.

**EDIT**

1. please make clear `what is echo` and `what is normal voice`.